# Is the PostgreSQL 'connection limit' shared across all users in a role?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have created a role that many users can share:

```
> create role foo_read_only connection limit 5;
```

I have then assigned permissions to that role:

```
> grant select on table1 to foo_read_only;
```

Then I have assigned that role to people:

```
> grant foo_read_only to fred;
> grant foo_read_only to ginger;
```

**Question:** Do both fred and ginger get a connection limit of 5, or would that limit be shared between them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `CONNECTION LIMIT` attribute only affects roles [that are able to log in](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createrole.html#AEN61227) (that is "users", or those roles which have the `LOGIN` attribute set).

Roles that are a member of another role with a `CONNECTION LIMIT` [do not inherit that limit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createrole.html#AEN61378), so in the situation you describe above `fred` and `ginger` would have the default connection limit of -1 (unlimited).

To limit `fred` and `ginger` you would need to specifically set a `CONNECTION LIMIT` on those roles.